# How to list all downloaded Bower dependencies?

Tags: bower

After executing `bower install`, some dependencies (with ~ and ^) were resolved to some latest version.

> e.g.
>
> - angular#~1.3.5 which resolved to 1.3.20
> - jquery-ui#~1.11.1 which resolved to 1.11.4

Is there a Bower command to list all downloaded dependencies with their respective version?

**Updated:**

So far I created a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh  
for filedir in "./bower_components/*" 
do
  grep '"version": ' $filedir/.bower.json 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line :

```
bower list
```